# How to automatically create a record in a model based on addition or deletion of data in a Many2many field in another model

Tags: python, python-3.x, odoo, erp, odoo-14

I've three models- `otl.rescuee`, `otl.qrcode` and `otl.qrcode.history`.

The fields used in `otl.rescuee` are:

```
class OtlRescuee(models.Model):
_name = 'otl.rescuee'
_inherit = ['image.mixin']
_description = "Rescuee"

name = fields.Char("Name", readonly=True)
address =  fields.Text(string="Address")
firstname = fields.Char("First Name")
lastname = fields.Char("Last Name")
nick_name = fields.Char("Preferred Name")
birth_date = fields.Date(string="Date of Birth")
caregiver_id = fields.Many2one('res.users', string="Caregiver")
support_cast_ids = fields.Many2many('res.partner', 'support_cast_rescuee_rel', 'support_cast_id', 'rescuee_id', string="Support Cast")
qr_ids = fields.Many2many('otl.qrcode', 'qrcode_rescuee_rel', 'rescuee_id', 'qrcode_id',  string='QR Codes')
```

The fields used in otl.qrcode are:

```
class OtlQrcodeCreation(models.Model):
_name = 'otl.qrcode'
_inherit = ['image.mixin']
_description = "QR code"

name = fields.Char(string='QR Code')
description = fields.Text(string="Description")
rescuee_ids = fields.Many2many('otl.rescuee', 'qrcode_rescuee_rel', 'qrcode_id', 'rescuee_id', string='Rescuees')
active = fields.Boolean(string='Active', default=True)
```

Similarly `otl.qrcode.history` is given by:

```
class OtlQrcodeHistory(models.Model):
_name = 'otl.qrcode.history'
_description = "QR Code History"

name = fields.Char(string="QR History", readonly=True, required=True, copy=False, default='New')
rescuee_id = fields.Many2one('otl.rescuee', string='Rescuee')
qrcode_id = fields.Many2one('otl.qrcode', string='QR Code')
start_date = fields.Date(string='Start Date')
end_date = fields.Date(string='End Date')
```

As you can see, `otl.rescuee` and `otl.qrcode` share a `many2many` relation(ie., `qr_ids` and `rescuee_ids` respectively). The `otl.qrcode` model is used to create `qrcodes` which can be later added as tags in `otl.rescuee` `qr_ids` field.

So, how do I automatically create a record in `otl.qrcode.history` based on the addition/deletion of data on `qr_ids` field, with the `start_date` being the date on which that particular record was added and `end_date` being the date that record was removed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In qrcode model, implement create and unlink methods. So when a qr code is first created, qrcode history object is automatically created with current date as start date. About addition of data on qr_ids, you can create a write method in qrcode model and put your logic there.

```
history_id = fields.One2many('otl.qrcode.history', 'qrcode_id', 'History')

@api.model
def create(self, value):
    history_id = self.env['otl.qrcode.history'].create({
            'name': 'name qr',
            'rescuee_id': rescuee_id,
            'start_date': fields.Date.today(),
            'end_date': None,
            'qr_id': self.id,
            })
    value['history_id'] = history_id
    new_qr_id = super(OtlQrcodeCreation, self).create(values)
    return super(OtlQrcodeCreation, self).write({'qr_id': new_qr_id})

@api.model
def unlink(self):
    self.history_id.write({'end_date': fields.Date.today()})
    return super(OtlQrcodeCreation, self).unlink()
```

In PosgreSQL Odoo, every model have create_date and write_date. You can make use of write_date the way you want it.